How to fix my SCSS so it's applying the text color?
might be best explain with an example
this is the HTML snippet of my breadcrumb. This comes with its own breadcrumbs.scss.
<div class="container">
  <div class="cmp-container">
    <div class="my-grid">
      <div class="breadcrumb container">
        <nav class="cmp-breadcrumb">
          <ol class="cmp-breadcrumb__list">
            <li class="cmp-breadcrumb__item">
              <a href="/content/page2.html" class="cmp-breadcrumb__item-link">
                <span class="cmp-breadcrumb__link-text">Go To Page2</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

"Go to Page2" is supposed to display in purple. But the selector is getting the color assigned in a different SCSS. It's currently displaying in pink.
There's obviously some specifity issues and I'm hoping you can help fix it (still using SASS).
PS. I've tried using "!important" in breadcrumb.scss and this fixes my issue but I consider that as a last resort.

This SCSS snippet from breadcrumbs.scss
.theme1 {
    .cmp-breadcrumb {
        .&__item-link {
                color: var(--bs-purple);
        }
    }
}

This the snippet of the other SCSS (
.theme1 {
    .container {
        a {
            color: var(--bs-pink);
            &:hover {
                color: var(--bs-pink);
            }
        }
    }
}


Please educate yourself on CSS Specificity. It's one of the most basic concepts you need to have a firm grasp on if you're supposed to work with CSS. Whenever !important helps, specificity is exactly your issue.

Is your .&__item-link correct? It fails validation in the Sass playground

Try [class$="__item-link"] instead of .&__item-link?

You have two problems going on there:

As phil noticed, you have invalid sass.  The correct syntax is:



    .cmp-breadcrumb {
        &__item-link { /* I removed the dot */
            color: var(--bs-purple);
        }
    }




Your css specificity is applying incorrectly:
For the purple color, the rule has a specificity of 0-2-0, whereas your pink has a 0-3-1 (2 classes + :hover = 3, and a nav element selector)
In order to fix this, reduce the specificity of the pink rule or increase the purple's one. I would go for the first approach as unnecessary descendant selectors hurt (a bit) performance

